# FusedLocationProviderClient keeps showing "Searching gps" notification

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gps

I would like to ask a clarification about the meaning of the "Searching gps" notification. I have a simple app that tries to retrieve user position via FusedLocationProviderClient with this code:

```
val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity as Activity)
fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                    mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                    // other trivial stuff here
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    // showing an error here
                }
```

Even when last location is retrieved android keeps showing the "Searching gps" notification (Ricerca gps in the screenshot below). As far as you know, this means that app is still searching for gps updates (and so draining battery) or is a simple message to notify the user that the app is using the gps? Thanks for the clarification, my device is a Xiaomi Redmi 5 Plus (MiUI)

[image]

Comment: Fused Location Provider might have found a location by some other means (cell towers, Wi-Fi etc.) but the phone hasn't established a GPS fix yet. It may take time. Even more so if you are testing indoors where GPS doesn't really work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but I'll take a stab here. I think one of two things is going on:

1. The notification is being explicitly shown by the MyFoody app and it's that app's responsibility to hide the notification once it no longer needs to be shown. You'd need to take care of clearing that notification in the listener's success and failure functions you've defined. Are your listeners being called? Do they clear the notification?

OR

2. It may be that Xiaomi has modified Android to show that notification on behalf of your app while it's retrieving location(s). If that's the case, then you'd need to figure out why this Xiaomi-modified Android version still thinks your app is trying to get a location. It could also just be a bug on Xiaomi's part, but I'd consider that as a last resort.

Comment: I'm not explicitly showing the notification from the app, I guess it's related to MiUi. When the position from gps is set, I can  remove the notification. That's isn't true when the gps is setting its position

Comment: So is one of your listener functions being called? If so, which one and does the notification disappear when the function is called or does it appear that there's a bug in MiUi that's not clearing the notification?

Comment: I guess it's a bug in MiUi not hiding notification. I have to remove it manually by touch